# Upgrading Joomla Version 1.5.20 to Joomla Version 2.5.4

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to upgrade Joomla Version 1.5.20 to Joomla Version 2.5.4.

I've upgraded other CMS's in the past, but Joomla seems to be a little different. Does anyone have any advice as to the best way to upgrade?

So far I've:

- Downloaded the entire site
- Exported the database via phpMyAdmin

I've installed MAMP and Joomla locally and I'm trying to replicate their site on my machine in attempt to upgrade locally before doing it live. I've loaded the template, but haven't been able to load the content yet.

There seems to be a lot of versions between 1.5.20 and 2.5.4, and it's making me a bit nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly upgrade from a Joomla! 1.5.x version to the 2.5.x line, it's a migration.

As the 2.5 line is a big change to Joomla! you will have to find 2.5 versions of:

- the template you're using
- any custom extensions (ie. components, plug-ins, modules etc)

[Version 2.5 has new technical requirements](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html) so you will need to check that your server meets those.

Once you've got all that resolved.

First thing you should do is upgrade a backup of your 1.5.x site to the latest version ie. [1.5.26 as it fixes some security issues](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5419-joomla-1526-released.html), and the recent versions included 1 or 2 bugs that help with the migration.

Once you have that working you will need to use a migration tool as discussed in [this document](http://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5). Please note that while this document references JUpgrade, you would probably be better off looking at one of [the other conversion tools](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration), especially the commercial products (which aren't expensive at all).

We're about half way through migrating over 200 client websites and while we started out with the free 'recommended' component we now use the commercial [SP Upgrade](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/15609) (*I have no affiliation with this product other than purchasing it and using it happily*).

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade joomla the plugin **JUpgrade** is one of the options. its quite easy tool.
updation can only required some clicks.
Here is steps.

**Step 1**

The very first thing you need to do is update your Joomla 1.5 website to the latest security update (1.5.25 at the time of writing). Click here for the tutorial on how to update your site.

**Step 2**

create a backup of your website.

**Step 3**

We are going to use jUpgrade to migrate our website. You can download jUpgrade from above link.

**Step 4**

Once you have downloaded jUpgrade, install it in existing joomla using the extension manager (Extensions -> Install / Uninstall).

[image]

Make sure that you have loggedin with Super Administrator. ( It required super administrator rights to migrate database and media.)

**Step 5**

You need to enable the System - Mootools Upgrade plugin before you can use jUpgrade so navigate to extensions then plugin manager, do a search for the plugin and enable it. (Extensions -> Plugin Manager)

**Step 6**

Click on Start Upgrade, It will now upgrading automatically as below till completion Popup.

Now click on administrator, you will see Joomla newer version Login page and make sure that all content transferred successfully ( It will transfer only contents that will supported in new Joomla version)
JUpgrade will create new directory. Download & install Joomla newer version to new directory and transfer media and contents in newer one.

[click here =](http://spjoshis.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upgrade-joomla-from-15to-25.html) to read More.